# PSTricks algebraic coordinates going from MikTeX to TeXLive

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, miktex, texlive, kile

I am using PSTricks and some tikz functions for preparing some sketches.

This snipped worked perfectly fine MikTeX on Windows 7

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newrgbcolor{colRM}{.7 .05 .2}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(17.0,10)
\def \xO {4.0}
\def \yO {1.7}
\rput[c](+{\xO+1.7,\yO-0.8}){ \textcolor{colRM}{ \small{ $\vec M$ } }   }
%\psgrid(0,0)(0,-5)(17,10)

\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

but does not work in Kile 2.1.0 on Ubuntu 12.04, i.e. TeXLive. The `+` results in `missing number treated as zero`.I tried to play with the braces position like `{\xO+1.7},{\yO-0.8}` or `{\xO+1.7} {\yO-0.8}` but that does not work. My workaround up to now is to use `\pgfmathsetmacro` in the previous lines and to use the result. 
While this incompatibility is sort of frustrating, as at work I have a Win7 computer and only using Linux at home, I'd like to know how to do that in Kile.

**Edit** file list according to request of David Carlisle

*This is the MikTexPortable Windows output:*

```
*File List*
scrartcl.cls    2015/02/07 v3.16 KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2015/02/07 v3.16 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
scrbase.sty    2015/02/07 v3.16 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2015/02/07 v3.16 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2015/02/07 v3.16 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2015/02/07 v3.16 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2015/02/07 v3.16 KOMA-Script package (type area)
german.sty    1998/07/08 v2.5e Support for writing german texts (br)
amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
dvips.def    2014/10/14 v3.0j Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
epic.sty    
eepic.sty    
color.sty    1999/02/16
color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
dvipsnam.def    2014/10/14 v3.0j Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
pstricks.tex    2014/10/25 v2.60 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
pst-fp.tex    2014/10/25 v2.60 `PST-fp' (hv)
pst-3dplot.sty    2010/01/01 package wrapper for pst-3dplot.tex (hv)
pst-3d.sty    2009/07/28 package wrapper for pst-3d.tex (hv)
pst-3d.tex    2010/02/14 v1.11 `PST-3d' (hv)
pst-plot.sty    2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)
pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
multido.sty    2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)
multido.tex    2010/05/14 v1.42 `multido' (tvz,hv)
pst-plot.tex    2014/08/23 1.70 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
pst-node.tex    2014/08/04 1.35 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
pst-3dplot.tex    2014/08/25 v2.01 `PST-3dplot' (hv)
fig2_base.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
***********
```

*This is the TeX Live Ubuntu output:*

```
*File List*
scrartcl.cls    2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
scrbase.sty    2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2009/03/25 v3.03 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2009/06/08 v3.03b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (type area)
german.sty    1998/07/08 v2.5e Support for writing german texts (br)
amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
amsfonts.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2009/08/28 v1.8 graphics configuration of TeX Live
dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
epic.sty    
eepic.sty    
color.sty    1999/02/16
color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
dvipsnam.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
pstricks.sty    2008/11/26 v0.40 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2009/05/19 v1.29 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-3dplot.sty    2009/07/28 package wrapper for pst-3dplot.tex (hv)
pst-3dplot.tex    2009/10/06 v1.86 `PST-3dplot' (hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
fig2_base.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
umsa.fd    2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A
umsb.fd    2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols B
***********
```

Comment: What should be the desired output? I only see a red "*M*" with a vector over it. (Is that it?)

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, this is the minimum working example in MikTeX, that does not work in Kile. In MikTeX it just produces a red vector M. In Kile I get with the same code "missing number treated as zero". (Sure the full sketch is more complicated)

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. Kile is an editor I see (never heard it before now), have you tried other editors to see if the result is the same?

Comment: @Alenanno, I guess it is more a MikTex for Windows vs Ubuntu problem, or some version numbers in PSTricks.

Comment: Well, I was proposing it to narrow the problem or to help identifying it.

Comment: add `\listfiles` to your preamble and compare the file list on the two logs (and post the list into your question here) this will show the version of all packages used

Comment: @Alenanno Sure, I will give it a try. On top of it I get different angles in `tikz` when using `atan2`. I had to swap the `x` and `y` arguments to get the same result in MikTeX/Windows and Kile/Ubuntu, but that is actually an independent qestion.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Working on it; as I am at home I need to get Windows machine first

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Found one, added the according output

Comment: @mikuszefski what can we say? The pstricks in the non working one is 2008 and in the working one it is 2013. That's several years for bugs to be fixed and syntax to be extended. You either need to update the system or find some old documentation for the syntax supported then. this is unrelated to kile or miktex or ubuntu.

Comment: similarly your "independent question" about tikz. One is tikz 2 and the other is tikz3, a major rewrite, differences are to be expected.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True, what can I say. I thought I keep my Ubuntu up to date and was expecting packages newer than on a portable Windows version. I will have to figure how to update those.

Comment: @mikuszefski The default TeXLive installed from the Ubuntu repositories is quite old, especially on 12.04. You should use the instructions here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/32374 to install the most recent version of TeXLive directly from TUG, instead of from the Ubunto repos.

Comment: @darthbith Thanks for the info, I already figured this out. Just installed the version from TUG. (internet installer was unbelievable slow, so eventually downloaded the iso). PATH is set. Now I am looking for a nice editor as the standard ubuntu install of Kile wants to work with the standard repository TexLive etc. On Windows I use the very simple [WinShell](http://www.winshell.de/)....balancing parentheses a little bit of highlighting and handle projects. I'll check the nice threads on this topic in tex.SE. Cheers